# Binary format for timed sequence

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, sequence, delay, gpio, nrf51

I am creating a BLE firmware implementing the Automation IO Service, which is able to accept commands to toggle output pins.

Also, I want to be able to send a sequence of outputs with delays in one single packet.

So, one packet could contain this information:

```
LED0(High),LED1(HIGH),LED2(HIGH) 
-> delay(1000) 
-> LED0(High),LED1(LOW),LED2(HIGH) 
-> delay(1000) 
-> LED0(LOW),LED1(HIGH),LED2(LOW) 
-> delay(1000) 
-> LED0(LOW),LED1(LOW),LED2(LOW)
```

Due to BLE's limitations the Packet format should be as space-efficient as possible.
The number of output pins is known in advance, so no need to encode the number or indices of outputs.

Creating this format sounds doable, but I hope to find a known, efficient and wide-spread standardized format for that.

Does such a format exist?

Comment: [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1)?

Comment: What if you serialize it in the most obvious way, then compress it with a general purpose compression algorithm such as DEFLATE?

Comment: I would like to avoid compression in order to keep it simple and power-efficient...